# Code doesnt work after pulling rst pin low

Tags: c, esp8266

I am trying to make an automatic house using ESP 8266 NodeMCU
Since this project will have to be charged from batteries, I need to act sparingly with energy.

My Products: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07Z63MFYC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I connected the RST and GND pin to my sensor and everything seems to be working well. But if I connect the sensors at the moment of connecting to the Wi-Fi, the code stops working.

My Code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

HTTPClient sender;
WiFiClient wifiClient;

const char* ssid = "xxx";
const char* password = "xxx";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.persistent( false );
  WiFi.mode( WIFI_STA );
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Verbunden!");
  if (sender.begin(wifiClient, "http://192.168.178.64:1880/update-sensor")) {
    int httpCode = sender.GET();
    if (httpCode > 0) {
      if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
        String payload = sender.getString();
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.printf("HTTP-Error: ", sender.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    sender.end();
  } else {
    Serial.printf("HTTP-Verbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden!");
  }
  ESP.deepSleep(0); 
}

void loop() {

}
```

I tried this code: `delay(5000);` on the start of setup() but it doesn't help me

Steps:
perfect-case:

1. I connect the magnetic switches (=door closed)
2. I connect ESP8266 to my PC
3. I disconnect the magnetic switches (=door opened)
4. I wait till WiFi is connected and ESP sends http request (takes about 10-30 sec.)
   P.S. HTTP-Error is ok, because I didn't start my server.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccr2F.png)

realistic-case:

1. I connect the magnetic switches (=door closed)
2. I connect ESP8266 to my PC
3. I disconnect the magnetic switches (=door opened)
4. After 4-6 seconds I close the "door" and my code stops.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpzPD.png)

So... I don't want to wait about 30 seconds to close my door in real life.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite (C?C++?Java?) forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Describe step-by-step what you are doing, what happens and how you detect that it works or doesn't work. What do you get on the serial connection in both cases.

Comment: What do you expect, if you pull RST low? The ESP8266 is supposed to stay reset until you release RST.

Comment: use `persistent` WiFi settings. it starts faster

Comment: Why do you want to _reset_ the ESP8266? Did you consider to let it run, and to use one of the GPIO inputs to detect the open door? The interval can be even shorter than 5 seconds. In idle phases, I'm sure that you can use some power-save modes. -- Or use a bit more external circuitry and let the ESP8266 switch off by itself, after it was switched on by the sensor.

Comment: Please convert the images to text and put them inside code blocks. If you highlight the line in the editor, and click the `{}` button in the row with bold it will make it a code block.